# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VALUE in RamlValidationService

Tags: java, yaml, restful-architecture, raml, raml-java-parser

I want to create a RAML validator that will get the [RAML URLs](http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml) resturn validation results. For that Im using [raml-java-parser](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-java-parser). As per its readme file I try to execute below line of code:

```
String sourceUrl = "http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml";
List<ValidationResult> results = RamlValidationService.createDefault().validate(sourceUrl);
```

And get below error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VALUE
```

Why I'm getting this error? Before that I got some class not found exceptions therefore I have applied below jar libraries manually.

```
> juniversalchardet_1.0.3_1.0.0.jar 
> raml_parser_0.8.11_1.0.0.jar
> rhino_1.7R4_1.0.0.jar 
> snakeyaml-1.16.jar
> jackson_databind_2.4.4_1.0.0.jar
```

I have tried below stuff as well. inputStream is the RAML content that I parsed through ByteArrayInputStream. But [this](http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml) is not a invalid RAML therefore I might doing something wrong.

[image: validation result]
[image: converting to RAML object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen this error. I suspect you may still miss dependencies.

Indeed, the Java RAML parser [has more dependencies](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.raml|raml-parser|0.8.11|jar) than these few JARs you've manually added. And the dependencies you see in the `pom` are just the tip of the iceberg, there are tons of transitive dependencies as well.

So: use a proper dependency manager (like Maven) for your project. It will take care of bringing all the dependencies (direct and transitive) for you. Besides, unless this is a toy project, you will need a proper build tool anyway.

Comment: Thanks @david,
is it ok to use URL of the RAML? 
Example: sourceUrl = "http://api.apihub.com/onpositive/api/espn-raml-api/espn.raml";

Comment: Yes it is possible to load a remote RAML over HTTP.