# Java RAML Parser: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VALUE

Tags: java, parsing, yaml, raml

This is the same error as here: [Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VALUE in RamlValidationService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402777/getting-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-value-in-ramlvalidationservice)

However, in that case, the problem was not using Maven for deps, but I am doing so.

My simple RAML file:

```
/echo:
    /{str}:
        uriParameters:
            str:
                type: string
        get:
            displayName: Used to retrieve a specific page
            responses:
                200:
                    displayName: Page returned successfully
                404:
                    displayName: Page not found
```

My Simple Java usage:

```
File apiDir = new File("api");

        File[] directoryListing = apiDir.listFiles();
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                RamlDocumentBuilder rdb = new RamlDocumentBuilder();
                System.out.println("________ child.getAbsolutePath(): "
                        + child.getAbsolutePath());
                if (child != null) {
                    try {
                        Raml raml = rdb.build(new FileReader(child));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
                        throw new RuntimeException("Problem with raml file: ", fnfe);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Ignoring file: " + child);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("api directory is not a directory.");
        }
```

my simple pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fastjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>boon</artifactId>
            <version>0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
            <artifactId>javapoet</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.raml</groupId>
            <artifactId>raml-parser</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is the fun error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: VALUE
    at org.raml.parser.utils.NodeUtils.<clinit>(NodeUtils.java:34)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.resolveTag(NodeVisitor.java:164)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.doVisitMappingNode(NodeVisitor.java:139)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.NodeVisitor.visitDocument(NodeVisitor.java:209)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlDocumentBuilder.build(YamlDocumentBuilder.java:90)
    at org.raml.parser.visitor.YamlDocumentBuilder.build(YamlDocumentBuilder.java:113)
    at my.group.App.main(App.java:27)
```

---

Edit 1: If I use straight SnakeYAML, all is well.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that issue?

Comment: @VladimirTikhomirov I ended up just using straight SnakeYAML to parse my RAML files...